# Erlang: "extending" an existing module with new functions

Tags: erlang

I'm currently writing some functions that are related to lists that I could possibly be reused.

My question is:

Are there any conventions or best practices for organizing such functions?

To frame this question, I would ideally like to "extend" the existing lists module such that I'm calling my new function the following way: lists:my_funcion().  At the moment I have lists_extensions:my_function().  Is there anyway to do this?

I read about erlang packages and that they are essentially namespaces in Erlang.  Is it possible to define a new namespace for Lists with new Lists functions?

Note that I'm not looking to fork and change the standard lists module, but to find a way to define new functions in a new module also called Lists, but avoid the consequent naming collisions by using some kind namespacing scheme.

Any advice or references would be appreciated.

Cheers.

Comment: Not to sound facetious, but it's open source.  You could fork the repository and add your changes to the lists module?

Comment: You could. The problem is that you then can't distribute your own source without also having to patch Erlang/OTP. Not an ideal solution.

Comment: i think that when we say extending an erlang module, we mean adding more functions or changing the existing ones. I thought all "adamstantonvan" wanted was to add his personal functions to be called from lists.erl

Comment: Sorry guys, I wasn't too clear with my question.  Just updated the question to clarify that I'm not looking to fork and change, simply to create another module of the same name but avoid naming collisions.

Comment: Why do you need to do that? Luckily we are not bound to 6 characters in module name as it used to be in old times, so you can make up plenty of names. There is nothing except private functions in Erlang module (no instance variables, no inheritance) you may want to access.

Comment: @Victor Moroz I see your point.  It's not so much a need, but more a curiosity whether Erlang has the capability.  I was thinking along the lines that if you're building generalized list functions that that could quite easily belong to the standard lists module, they could be called from Lists through some kind of namespacing or path configuration.  What if I wanted to clone your Lists module?  And then I have my own?  I could end up with many modules all with related functions. And what if I named my module the same as yours?

Comment: issues with 'sticky directories' would occur if u were to create another lists module of your own.The emulator loads the lists.beam on start up and so will throw an error if it discovers another lists module

Answer (score 5):

> To frame this question, I would ideally like to "extend" the existing lists module such that I'm calling my new function the following way: lists:my_funcion(). At the moment I have lists_extensions:my_function(). Is there anyway to do this?

No, so far as I know.

> I read about erlang packages and that they are essentially namespaces in Erlang. Is it possible to define a new namespace for Lists with new Lists functions?

They are [experimental and not generally used](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4503131/why-arent-erlang-packages-used). You could have a module called `lists` in a different namespace, but you would have trouble calling functions from the standard module in this namespace.

Comment: As far as I know, there is no solution in Erlang. Ocaml and Standard ML has a beautiful solution based upon including signatures and opening modules in new namespaces. But for Erlang, this is a no-go solution.

Answer (score 1):

I give you reasons why *not* to use `lists:your_function()` and instead use `lists_extension:your_function()`:

- Generally, the Erlang/OTP Design Guidelines state that each "Application" -- libraries are also an application -- contains modules. Now you can ask the system [what application did introduce a specific module?](http://www.erlang.org/doc/design_principles/applications.html) This system would break when modules are fragmented.

However, I do understand why you would *want* a `lists:your_function/N`:

- It's easier to use for the author of `your_function`, because he needs the `your_function(...)` a lot when working with `[]`. *When another Erlang programmer -- who knows the `stdlb` -- reads this code, he will not know what it does. This is confusing.*
- It looks more concise than `lists_extension:your_function/N`. *That's a matter of taste.*

Answer (score 1):

I think this method would work on any distro:

You can make an application that automatically rewrites the core erlang modules of whichever distribution is running. Append your custom functions to the core modules and recompile them before compiling and running your own application that calls the custom functions. This doesn't require a custom distribution. Just some careful planning and use of the file tools and BIFs for compiling and loading.
* You want to make sure you don't append your functions every time. Once you rewrite the file, it will be permanent unless the user replaces the file later. Could use a check with module_info to confirm of your custom functions exist to decide if you need to run the extension writer.

Pseudo Example:

```
lists_funs() -> ["myFun() -> <<"things to do">>."].
extend_lists() -> 
   {ok, Io} = file:open(?LISTS_MODULE_PATH, [append]),
   lists:foreach(fun(Fun) -> io:format(Io,"~s~n",[Fun]) end, lists_funs()),
   file:close(Io),
   c(?LISTS_MODULE_PATH).
```

* You may want to keep copies of the original modules to restore if the compiler fails that way you don't have to do anything heavy if you make a mistake in your list of functions and also use as source anytime you want to rewrite the module to extend it with more functions. 
* You could use a list_extension module to keep all of the logic for your functions and just pass the functions to list in this function using `funName(Args) -> lists_extension:funName(Args).`
* You could also make an override system that searches for existing functions and rewrites them in a similar way but it is more complicated.
I'm sure there are plenty of ways to improve and optimize this method. I use something similar to update some of my own modules at runtime, so I don't see any reason it wouldn't work on core modules also.

Answer (score 0):

i guess what you want to do is to have some of your functions accessible from the lists module. It is good that you would want to convert commonly used code into a library.

one way to do this is to test your functions well, and if their are fine, you copy the functions, paste them in the lists.erl module **(WARNING: Ensure you do not overwrite existing functions, just paste at the end of the file)**. this file can be found in the path **`$ERLANG_INSTALLATION_FOLDER/lib/stdlib-{$VERSION}/src/lists.erl`**. Make sure that you add your functions among those exported in the lists module (in the `-export([your_function/1,.....])`), to make them accessible from other modules. Save the file.

Once you have done this, we need to recompile the lists module. You could use an `EmakeFile`. The contents of this file would be as follows:

```
{"src/*", [verbose,report,strict_record_tests,warn_obsolete_guard,{outdir, "ebin"}]}.
```

Copy that text into a file called **`EmakeFile`**. Put this file in the path: **`$ERLANG_INSTALLATION_FOLDER/lib/stdlib-{$VERSION}/EmakeFile`**.

Once this is done, go and open an erlang shell and let its **`pwd()`**, the current working directory be the path in which the EmakeFile is, i.e. **`$ERLANG_INSTALLATION_FOLDER/lib/stdlib-{$VERSION}/`**.

Call the function: **`make:all()`** in the shell and you will see that the module lists is recompiled. Close the shell.

Once you open a new erlang shell, and assuming you exported you functions in the lists module, they will be running the way you want, right in the lists module.
Erlang being open source allows us to add functionality, recompile and reload the libraries. This should do what you want, success.

Comment: This will work, but it does alter the base module. I think the question was framed such that it was hinted if you can monkey-patch an existing module.